# Kernel Died when plotting CNN learning history

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I was creating a CNN using keras. Everything was fined until I try to plot the learning history of
the model.

```
# Train the CNN
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch = 143, epochs = 20, validation_data = validation_generator, validation_steps = 18)

# Display the loss and accuracy during training
acc = history['acc']
val_acc = history['val_acc']
loss = history['loss']
val_loss = history['val_loss']
epochs = range(1,len(acc) + 1)
```

After preparing data for the plot, I wrote the following code:

```
plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'bo', label = 'Training acc')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'b', label = 'Validation acc')
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.figure()
plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'bo', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'b', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Then Jupyter Notebook show me 'The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically'

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. Updating python and tensorflow to 3.9 and 2.10 respectively.